# Dynamics 365 how to restore a datasource for a table on an extension form?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations

I have a form on AX lets call it "**Records_Form**", the form has a master datasource lets call it "**Records_DS**" that is connected to a table that is called "**Records**".

Now i created a new AX project and add new extension to the upper mentioned Form lets call it "**Records_Frorm.Extension**", on that extension form i added a new extension to the table "**Records.Extension**", where i need to add a new field, however when i open the extension form and try to click "restore" in the context menu of the master datasource i have an error massage that says that the datasource is locked.

Also I couldn't add a new datasource for the extension table.

my question is: how can i access the new field in the extension form, should i douplicate the datasource that connected to the same table, or is there a way to restore the datasource.

Comment: Can you try this? 1) Refresh model 2) Export form extension 3) Delete same 4) Re-import it

Comment: Try building your model fully from the Dynamics AX menu too.

Comment: it didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a workarround by adding an extension table that has the new records, and after that close the project and open it again will solve the problem without reset the datasource.